# Return statements in validation functions

Tags: python, validation, return, conventions, typechecking

I was looking through https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py and stumbled across some type checking functions (I simplified them, original is _check_int_field)

```
def foo(year, month, day):
    year = check_int(year)
    month = check_int(month)
    day = check_int(day)
```

check_int returns the value inputted (if it's an integer) - and raises ValueError if it's not. Let me shorten the function they used:

```
def check_int(value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError('integer argument expected, got %s' % type(value))
```

My question is: What's the meaning behind the return statement? Surely you could just have it implemented as

```
def check_int(value):
    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError('integer argument expected, got %s' % value)
```

This would change the foo function to (where you wouldn't have to define the variables, but simply use the foo arguments)

```
def foo(year, month, day):
    check_int(year)
    check_int(month)
    check_int(day)
```

This would raise an TypeError if the input type is wrong - and simply keep on going with the function arguments if not, without having to define any variables. So why do they return the input variable, if they dont modify it, but simply check it?

Comment: Do you mean [`_check_int_field`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L383)? Because in some cases it *does* return something other than just its argument. Your "simplification" is profoundly unhelpful; your posted version *could* be replaced, because it's not representative of the real thing.

Comment: Yes, but it only returns value, value.__index__() or value.__name()__, which shouldn't really change the variable - it's gonna be the same integer regardless. What functionality does __index__() and __name()__ provide, that would require the return statement?

Comment: as @rdas pointed out here you left out a pretty important section of the code, mainly being the `try` block. This has the potential to change the value of `value`. if it was a simple type check you could use `assert isinstance(value, int), "Type of %s should be int"%s` rather than defining functions for this at all.

Comment: If the function returns a value and you don't want it, you are free to ignore it. If the function does *not* return a value but you need it, well, you're out of luck. The `return` simply makes it more general. Consider a call like `check_int(x + 3)`; if its valid, you don't have a reference to *what* is valid, and you need to compute it again.

Comment: What do you mean *"shouldn't really change the variable"*? How does returning an attribute of the parameter instead of the parameter itself *not* change the variable?!

Comment: I edited my post to provide the originial function (my bad for neglecting it). Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I agree that pure validation functions may as well be `void` i.e. return nothing and raise an exception if required.

However, in this particular case, the `_check_int_field` function is actually used like this:

```
year = _check_int_field(year)
```

And this makes sense because in the `_check_int_field` they do this:

```
try:
    value = value.__int__()
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError('__int__ returned non-int (type %s)' %
                        type(value).__name__)
    return value
```

So the function is actually doing more than just validation. In which case, it makes sense for the function to return the value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It was (kind of) was I was expecting - I simply just don't quite understand the purpose of  __int__ and __index__, which led to my confusion